# SharePoint 2013 Event ID 7362 High CPU Problem

Tags: 2013, iis, cpu

I'm getting Event ID 7362 error at front end server at our SharePoint 2013 farm. I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20699.sharepoint-2010-event-id-7362-the-super-user-account-utilized-by-the-cache-is-not-configured.aspx) solution for SharePoint 2010 and I guess it is suitable for SharePoint 2013 too.

My questions is, does Event 7362 cause high CPU problem on IIS worker process? I'm getting this error many times recently and when this occurs IIS worker process consumes %99 CPU and IIS doesn't response requests.

[image]

[image]

Also I found that there is [an update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114352/december-8-2015-update-for-sharepoint-foundation-2013-kb3114352) for high CPU problem at SharePoint 2013. Does this resolve high CPU problem or should I configure object cache super user account even I install this update?

[image]

Here is front end server properties

[image]

Comment: Whats your servers hardware?

Comment: Hi @Christoffer I've just updated question and added hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can cause high CPU, Basically if you have site collection with Publishing Site template or Publishing featured enabled then you need to configure the Object Cache ( Super USer and Super Reader). This will help SharePoint to return the requested content quickly rather making a tour to SQL.

An other thing, Its depend upon number of web application in the farm along with the hardware of the servers.